# Paint.setStrokeJoin doesn't work with canvas.drawLines

Tags: android, canvas

I am trying to draw a line chart using `canvas.drawLines(...)`, but it seems that the lines are not properly connected. As I understand using `Paint.setStrokeJoin` should use the miter join:

```
chartLinePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
chartLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
chartLinePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
chartLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(6.0f);
```

How do I fix this problem and make the lines properly joined?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding `chartLinePaint.setStrokeMiter(3.0f)` to see if something changes? Or have you tried changing the stroke join mode to BEVEL or ROUND?

Comment: @MatPag Yes, I've tried everything, none of these worked. Seems like setStrokeJoin is ignored if you don't use canvas.drawPath.

Comment: Paint are applied only when you draw them with path. I already expected you using it in this way. In `drawLine` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawLine(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) there is a paragraph with: 'the Style is ignored in the paint' so I expect the same thing for `drawLines`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I told you in the comment, `Paint` objects are fully applied only when you draw them with `Path`.

In [drawLine](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawLine(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) documentation there is a paragraph with: '**the Style is ignored in the paint**' and the same thing is applied to `drawLines` method.

To test this, I created a simple custom view:

```
class CanvasTestView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val textPaint1 = Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeJoin = Paint.Join.MITER
        strokeWidth = 12.0f
        color = Color.RED
    }

    private val textPaint2 = Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeJoin = Paint.Join.MITER
        strokeWidth = 12.0f
        color = Color.BLUE
    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        canvas?.apply {

            val floatArray = floatArrayOf(250f, 550f, 450f, 200f, 450f, 200f, 650f, 700f)
            drawLines(floatArray, textPaint2)

            val path = Path()
            path.moveTo(200f, 500f)
            path.lineTo(400f, 200f)
            path.lineTo(600f, 700f)
            drawPath(path, textPaint1)
        }

    }
}
```

And the result is this:

[image]

So using `drawLines` partially apply the styles of `Paint` obj, like colours, but is not applying `strokeJoin` like properties. `drawPath` seems to apply all of them instead.

If you have a performance problem maybe you can try to cache the result somewhere, pre-compute the animation or try with a simpler one.

> Remember that if you don't have particular requirements there is this
>   awesome library: [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) which already has some built-in animations

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

> As you may have noticed in the Android documentation, you can’t apply
>   a style to a `drawLine`.

[ref](https://acupofdev.wordpress.com/2012/01/24/android-apply-a-style-on-a-canvas-drawline/)

From the [Canvas documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLine(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint))

> ## drawLine:
>
> ```
> public void drawLine (float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY, Paint paint)
> ```
>
> Draw a line segment with the specified start and stop x,y coordinates,
>   using the specified paint.
>
> **Note that since a line is always "framed", the Style is ignored in the
>   paint.**
>
> Degenerate lines (length is 0) will not be drawn.
>
> ## drawLines:
>
> ```
> public void drawLines (float[] pts, int offset, int count, Paint paint)
> ```
>
> Draw a series of lines. Each line is taken from 4 consecutive values
>   in the pts array. Thus to draw 1 line, the array must contain at least
>   4 values. This is **logically the same as drawing the array** as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> drawLine(pts[0], pts[1], pts[2], pts[3]) 
> followed by:
> drawLine(pts[4], pts[5], pts[6], pts[7])
> ```
>
> and so on.
>
> ## Solution
>
> If you need to apply a `style`, the solution is to use `drawPath` instead.
>   It will apply the `style` set in the `paint` object.

Comment: The problem is that drawPath is much slower than drawLines. I am trying to render line charts with smooth animations so using drawPath is impossible due to performance issues.

Comment: @makovkastar Your question was `Paint.setStrokeJoin doesn't work with canvas.drawLines`. There was ***no mention of*** `I am trying to render line charts with smooth animations so using drawPath is impossible due to performance issues`.

Comment: You are right, my bad. I didn't mention that Canvas.drawPath was not suitable for my needs because of performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for to use the `StrokeJoin` or `StrokeCap` with `DrawPath()`, you can try `SkPathEffect` such as `CreateCorner()`:

[MS Docs, SkiaSharp, but kind of the same.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/curves/effects)