# Canvas.drawLines() produces gaps between lines

Tags: android, canvas

I use `drawLines()` on my dataset of points. It's drawn perfectly when it starts from (0,0), but when the dataset starts from another point it produces some gaps.

Here the chart starting with (0, 0) (added small line at left bottom):

[image]

Here it starts from from (83, 56) and produces gap:

[image]

**What I've tried:**

1. Setting on/off anti-alias.
2. Different datasets (they all produce gap at the top y point if there is nothing drawn at (0, 0).
3. I've read about trying `drawPath()`, but since I need to draw lots of lines it was said to be not as effecient as `drawLines()`.

Here are some snippets from my project:

**My dataset:**
`x = {
0,12,83,84,84,121,121,128,128,151,151,173,173,203,203,217,217,224,224,229,229,253,253,294,294,305,305,331,331,355,355,364,364,409,409,411,411,416,416,431,431,448,448,497,497,504,504,508,508,536,536,582,582,586,586,630,630,646,646,660,660,689,689,728,728,761,761,768,768,798,798,822,822,860,860,894,894,908,908,952,952,996,996,1039,1039,1085,1085,1085,1085,1099,1099,1119,1119,1133,1133,1169 
}`

`y = {
0,12,56,115,115,220,220,232,232,170,170,350,350,117,117,157,157,205,205,290,290,184,184,127,127,181,181,231,231,210,210,278,278,142,142,120,120,299,299,29,29,290,290,50,50,258,258,127,127,203,203,168,168,27,27,27,27,83,83,116,116,228,228,295,295,62,62,299,299,121,121,216,216,266,266,164,164,234,234,116,116,182,182,130,130,208,208,218,218,202,202,85,85,59,59,114
}`

**How I set my Paint:**

```
private void init() {
    chartPaint = new Paint();
    chartPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    chartPaint.setStrokeWidth(4);
    chartPaint.setColor(color);
}
```

**My onDraw():**

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();

    // let chart start from the most left without gaps
    canvas.translate(0, viewHeight);

    // TODO: find place to move calcs outside onDraw()
    final float xScale = (float)  viewWidth / (Util.getMax(x) - Util.getMin(x));
    final float yScale = (float) -viewHeight / (Util.getMax(y) - Util.getMin(y));

    valuesScaled = new float[values.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        valuesScaled[i] = (i%2==0) ? values[i] * xScale : values[i] * yScale;
    }

    canvas.drawLines(valuesScaled, chartPaint);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

`values` array is where `x` and `y` arrays are stored alternatively, i.e. first 4 elements of `values` are `{x[0], y[0], x[1], y[1], ...}`

`viewWidth` and `viewHeight` are taken from `onSizeChange()`.

Comment: The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55246353/paint-setstrokejoin-doesnt-work-with-canvas-drawlines/55247930?noredirect=1#comment97246851_55247930). You **cannot** use `Canvas.drawLines()` you **have to use** `drawPath()` to get what you want. You could use `drawLines()` as a kind of *preview*  and in the background run `drawPath()` and then use that when it has finished drawing.

Comment: @JonGoodwin Thanks for the comment. I've tried ``drawPath()`` and set stroke join. It produces the same gap. Do you know the possible reason for this?

Comment: Yes. When the angle is really sharp (as in your second, highlighted peak), the **miter** end-point can  recede to infinity. What you do is set a limit with **.e.g.** `chartPaint.setStrokeMiter(6)` see these image examples [`stroke-miterlimit`](https://web.archive.org/web/20111209121128/http://www.croczilla.com/bits_and_pieces/svg/samples/linestroke/linestroke.xml). You could use a round end-point, or use a cap. With thin lines, maybe you just need a cap and so use the faster `Canvas.drawLines()`. Have a play and see...

Comment: @JonGoodwin thank you. you can post an answer - I'll accept it. Btw, you know any good resources (articles/talks/book) on android canvas/custom views?

Comment: look at my back catalog of answers on graphics (my specialty) I will give you an answer, but time-poor and I only give what I consider a good answer...stay tuned... ;O)

Comment: set style stroke

Answer (score 0):

You are skipping some points in your code at the beginning of the array. You have for X:

```
0,12,83,84,84,121,121,...
```

That should be:

```
0,12,12,83,83,84,84,121,121,...
```

See [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawLines(float%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Paint))